# I need to install "docker pull bitnami/python:3.8.12-debian-10-r156" but I keep getting "permission denied"

Tags: linux, docker, debian, permission-denied

[the problem that pops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppY1d.png)

how can I install it? got to get this exact version...

Comment: (Please don't include links to screen shots of error messages; include the text of the error directly in your future questions.)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to run docker command with sudo:

   `sudo docker pull bitnami/python:3.8.12-debian-10-r156`
2. If you wanna make docker not requiring sudo, so you can run docker commands without sudo you have to run the following commands:

   `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
   `newgrp docker`